Avoiding parallel fifths in harmonization
Guides on tonal harmony suggest avoiding parallel fifths and octaves (though I am not sure why, since, unlike in counterpoint, losing voice individuality is not an issue.) Here is an example of poor voice leading from Fred Harz Harmonielehre für Gitarre:

Q: How can this be avoided (assuming that the soprano voice/melody is given)?
Two options that come to my mind are:

changing voicing from close to wide (or vice versa)
using different chord progression


"losing voice individuality is not an issue": but it is.  Parallel fifths and octaves cause a distinct change in texture of a four-voice chorale.  But one thing that people tend to underappreciate is that treatises on realizing figured bass often include parallels in their examples, for example when they show how to create dynamic contrast by playing fuller chords for louder passages.  Parallela were not quite as taboo as some assume, at least in certain contexts.

Parallel fifths and octaves are avoided to avoid medieval-like sonority. Yes, these are in essence Renaissance rules.
These can in 99.99% of cases be avoided by changing the inner voicings only.
I strongly recommend Walter Piston's Harmony to learn more about this.

In order to properly advise on chorale voicings, we really need more than just the two chords, as the best answers will change depending on where we're going with our chords.  So we'll presume certain destination chords as chord #3.
Since all three examples have the bass voice as a component, let's look at what we can do there.
In a), we are going from a D major to an E major.  Presuming the next chord is an A major (most likely in a circle-of-fifths progression), we could replace the "D-E-A?" bassline with "D-B-A" without generating parallel 5ths.
In b), we've got two offenses -- parallel fifths and parallel octaves, both of which are no-nos in traditional four-part voicing.  To go from an A major to B major chord while keeping the soprano at E-F#, we'll need several changes:

Change the initial A-A-C#-E chord (from bottom to top) to a different inversion, e.g., C#-E-A-E.  This will let us
change the voicing of the second chord from B-B-D#-F# to to B-D#-F#-F#, which (barely) obeys the rules.

In c), we have two offenses again -- parallel everything...  So this time, we'll play with the inner two voices: change the first chord from A-E-A-C to A-C-E-C and we're good.

The answer for avoiding parallel fifths is basically to rearrange voices so that doesn't happen. In addition to changing from open to closed position (or the reverse), you might double different notes in the chords and/or have some notes of the chords flow in different directions to the nearest chord tones.
The specifics (as another answer by Tom Williams already said) really depend on the exact situation.
But I really wanted to address this element of the question:

though I am not sure why, since, unlike in counterpoint, losing voice
individuality is not an issue.

Voice independence is a compositional choice.  When voices move in parallel (particularly parallel octaves and/or fifths, but also to a lesser extent block-like motion with other intervals), we change from a situation where there are "four independent voices" to "block chords moving together."
In many modern pop/rock styles, parallel motion is frequently used for effect.  The whole point sometimes is to feel like there are these weighty "chords" moving in parallel in big blocks together.
Classical harmony teaching tends to focus sometimes on harder compositional choices in order to instruct students and train them to be sensitive to various elements. If you never spend time learning the different sounds of parallel fifths vs. avoiding parallel fifths, your ear may not recognize them as clearly -- you may just have a vague feeling of "stronger motion" or "fusion" of some sort when voices move together in parallel, but you won't be able to identify it as specifically.
Learning to avoid parallel fifths teaches you to hear and have the ability to make that compositional choice.  In classical harmony, independent voices (which didn't move in lockstep together) were valued for many centuries.  Having them move together was generally for special effect or only when doubling in a thick texture.
So, learning about the "tricks" of avoiding parallel fifths allows you the ability to decide when you "lose voice individuality" (as you put it) and only care about chords vs. when you actually want to keep voices independent.

Thank you for addressing the issue of the parallel fifths. I hadn't realised that it was a separate interesting question.

Avoiding parallel (or covered) fifths and octaves between the bass and the melody is a good idea even in a chordal texture. The bass may jump more than in a Baroque 2-part invention but these two parts stand out. They should make good (or at least not bad) 2-part counterpoint. When editing my compositions, I find that parts that sound thin (like something missing) happen when I slip in parallel octaves (and even fifths.) Inversions and non-chord tones in the bass can alleviate the problem. As an experiment, one can take a popular song, add the middle chords as blocks, or arpeggios, and then make the bass identical to the melody. The bass should support rather than double the melody.
